# How can I increase initialization speed of my WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I am new to WPF.

In my wpf application, I have a Window with a `DataGrid`,  I load records from database to the `DataGrid` using Linq lambda expression.

The records are loaded during window's initialization, due to the large number of records in database, window initialization takes a long time and the application becomes unresponsive.

My team lead suggests me to **make it to bind its to way as UI Initialization then after binding to database (someone please help to edit this)**, but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long process stalling UI responsiveness, usually the best answer is to make the long process asynchronous - so load the grid data in a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and when it's finished then populate the grid.